# Getting resolved thymeleaf template

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to resolve a thymeleaf template but, as the return of the process() method, I'm getting the name of the template. I would like to get the raw html code to store it in the data layer for future use.

```
@Override
public String process(String template, Map<String, Object> model) {

    String process = templateEngine.process(template, new Context(config.getLocale(), model));
    return process;
}
```

I've tried to use all of the resolvers but they all work the same way. Is there any way to do this without reading the html file as a string and parsing for target pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a template configured as **RAW** ([More info about Template Mode](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#what-kind-of-templates-can-thymeleaf-process)).

For example in a `@Configuration` class define this:

```java
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {
  
    @Bean(name = "rawTemplateEngine")
    public TemplateEngine rawTemplateEngine() {
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(rawTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }
    
    private ITemplateResolver rawTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/"); //or whatever other directory you have the files
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");       //if they are html files
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.RAW);
        templateResolver.setForceTemplateMode(true); //to turn off suffix-based choosing
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
        templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }
  }
```

Please note, without `setForceTemplateMode` the smart template mode resolution overrides `setTemplateMode` ([Info about smart template resolution](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/606)).

Then, in the class that you need this bean, autowire it:

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("rawTemplateEngine")
TemplateEngine templateEngineRaw;
```

And then call:

```java
String process = templateEngineRaw.process(template, new Context(config.getLocale()));
```